# Why are there 500+ entries in the Late Answers queue?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, review, late-answers

[image: Far too many "Late Answers" in the review queue]

On inspection, it looks like many "late answers" from years ago have been added to the review queue.

Is this a change to, or an error in, the algorithms that select which answers get added to the queue?

Comment: Well, get to work. LAs are rare. This is an opportunity for people to rack up their counts. I'll stay away so others can make some progress towards review badges.

Comment: @gung To be fair, having started to get through a few, a decent proportion of them could actually do with a review!

Comment: I imagine that's true. My comment wasn't supposed to mean that you should feel obliged to do all of them.

Comment: @gung Yes no such obligation is felt, though how you managed to get to 1000 reviews yourself without such unusual events I have no idea, they are as rare as hen's teeth! :) I do think it'd be a shame if they just all get removed from the queue, it's an interesting opportunity to go through and fix up some long-standing stuff.

Comment: See [Jon Ericson's answer on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267080/208518) for some background on this.

Comment: Are reviews prioritized on your favourite tags? I'm only getting genetics, multiple comparisons, and FDR questions/answers which are my "favourites".

Comment: For users who haven't used the site for many years, it does seem a bit pointless leaving extensive written feedback. So I am probably not doing as much justice in my reviews as I normally would, just looking for howlers, things that need down/up-voting, and things that could do with a copy-edit such as adding links and full citations.

Comment: I've hit the "Thank you for reviewing 20 late answers today; come back in 3 hours to continue reviewing" limit. Whoever knew there was one! A couple of other people have also maxed out their 20 so we're down to 400 already. It doesn't look like the queue will take long to shift. (Which means I won't be able to add much to my review tally. Boo.)

Comment: Yeah, you have a max of 20 reviews per queue per (GMT) calendar day. It is unlikely anyone will be able to get to `reviewer` from this alone, but hopefully it will help get a lot of people started.

Comment: @ChrisC, at the top, beside the gray "Late Answers", there should be a link called "filter". If you click that, you should be able to request only posts w/ specified tags.

Comment: From the 20 reviews that I completed, it looks like this was a worthwhile exercise. The posts had been on our site for a while, but many of them needed some attention. If the SE team decided to raise the threshold even further, thus putting more old posts into the queue, then on this basis I would be supportive.

Comment: @gung, Thanks! Never knew that existed.

Comment: Late Answers queue has been cleared some minutes ago, so it took ~16 hours to clear 500+ entries. Not bad.

Comment: Nice work on the late answers, guys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There were more than 500 entries because the criterion for sending late answers to the queue has changed.

Before the change only late answers from users with reputation up to 10 had their answers sent there; now the threshold is 50. With this new criterion, many old and late answers posted by users with reputation ranging from 10 to 50 were sent retroactively to the review page.

This is the Meta reference pointed out by JNat:
[Can we raise the bar for reputation for late answers to bypass the review queue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266696/can-we-raise-the-bar-for-reputation-for-late-answers-to-enter-the-review-queue)